# Validation of a column entry to a dynamically created DataGrid - compiles but displays nothing

Tags: wpf, validation

Following many examples here, I created a dynamically created DataGrid from a collection. When I include the DataValidation component for one of the columns, the following code compiles, but displays nothing. Without the validation component, it works. I would appreciate it very much if an experienced member could point out my error.

Thank very much.

i. konuk

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="SimpleGridX.MainWindow"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SimpleGridX"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

        mc:Ignorable="d"

        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid>

        <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497" Height="299" 
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >

            <DataGrid Name="dgSimpleX" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                      SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectionMode="Extended" 
                      CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True">

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                        <Binding Path="[Age]">
                            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                <local:MyValidationRule />
                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                        </Binding>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn>

            </DataGrid>

        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Window code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.ComponentModel;

namespace SimpleGridX
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            // Create an instance of the PersonCollection class
            PersonCollection people =
                new PersonCollection();

            InitializeComponent();
            dgSimpleX.SelectionUnit = DataGridSelectionUnit.CellOrRowHeader;
            dgSimpleX.ItemsSource = people;
            dgSimpleX.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("FirstName", ListSortDirection.Descending));

        }
    }
}
```

Object Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Globalization;

namespace SimpleGridX
{
    class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string firstName;
        private string lastName;
        private float age;
        private string occupation;

        // Each property calls the OnPropertyChanged method
        // when its value changed, and each property that 
        // affects the Person's Description, also calls the 
        // OnPropertyChanged method for the Description property.

        public string FirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return firstName;
            }
            set
            {
                if (firstName != value)
                {
                    firstName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
                    OnPropertyChanged("Description");
                }
            }
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get
            {
                return lastName;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this.lastName != value)
                {
                    this.lastName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
                    OnPropertyChanged("Description");
                }
            }
        }

        public float Age
        {
            get
            {
                return age;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this.age != value)
                {
                    this.age = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Age");
                    OnPropertyChanged("Description");
                }
            }
        }

        public string Occupation
        {
            get { return occupation; }
            set
            {
                if (this.occupation != value)
                {
                    this.occupation = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Occupation");
                    OnPropertyChanged("Description");
                }
            }
        }

        // The Description property is read-only,
        // and is composed of the values of the
        // other properties.
        public string Description
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Format("{0} {1}, {2} ({3})",
                                     firstName, lastName, age, occupation);
            }
        }

        // The ToString returns the Description,
        // so that it is displayed by default when 
        // the Person object is a binding source.
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Description;
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        /// Implement INotifyPropertyChanged to notify the binding
        /// targets when the values of properties change.
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(
            string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                // Raise the PropertyChanged event
                this.PropertyChanged(
                    this,
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(
                        propertyName));
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }

    #region ValidationRule

    public class MyValidationRule : ValidationRule
    {
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            float myage = (float)0.0;

            try
            {
                if (((string)value).Length > 0)
                {
                    myage = (float)Decimal.Parse((string)value, NumberStyles.Any, cultureInfo);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return new ValidationResult(false, "Illegal ccharacters");
            }

            if ((myage < (float)0.0) || (myage > (float)75.0))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(false, "Not in range");
            }
            else
            {
                return new ValidationResult(true, null);
            }

        }


    }

    #endregion

}
```

Collection:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace SimpleGridX
{
    class PersonCollection : ObservableCollection<Person>
    {
        public PersonCollection()
        {
            // Load the collection with dummy data
            //
            Add(new Person()
            {
                FirstName = "Elin",
                LastName = "Binkles",
                Age = 26,
                Occupation = "Professional"
            });

            Add(new Person()
            {
                FirstName = "Samuel",
                LastName = "Bourts",
                Age = 28,
                Occupation = "Engineer"
            });

            Add(new Person()
            {
                FirstName = "Alan",
                LastName = "Jonesy",
                Age = 37,
                Occupation = "Engineer"
            });

            Add(new Person()
            {
                FirstName = "Sam",
                LastName = "Nobles",
                Age = 25,
                Occupation = "Engineer"
            });
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Age property should be bound without square brackets.
Also.
It'll be bound to two columns if you leave autogenerate true.
Edit:

Also.
You need any columns inside a columns collection.
What you have there produces an error when I try it, because it tries to make your age  column into an item and then the code tries to set itemssource.

```
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age"> 
              ……
          </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Andy: Thank you indeed very much. Removing brackets did not solve the problem. In order to solve the second issue you have raised I slimmed the XAML but no progress :                           <Binding Path="Age">
       <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                <local:MyValidationRule />
       </Binding.ValidationRules>
</Binding>

Comment: You also need a columns collection if you're defining any columns. See update in answer.